# Why does πεντάμορφη mean "beautiful"?

Tags: etymology, greek

How does "five-formed / five-shaped", πεντάμορφη, mean "beautiful"?

Such that it's used as in translation of "Beauty and the Beast" movie titles, and accepted by Google Translate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Classical Greek, [*πεντάμορφος*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=penta/morfos) is a perfectly straightforward compound adjective made up of *πεντά-* ‘five-, penta-’ and *μορφή* ‘shape’. Its meaning is also transparent, ‘having five shapes’, and it is apparently an epithet describing evil things.

The Modern Greek word *πεντάμορφος* is a different word, which does *not* mean ‘five-shaped’. You can’t see it from the word itself, but it is actually a compound of *πεντά-* ‘five-’ (here used as an intensifier meaning ‘five-fold’ or ‘five times’ – or more generally, ‘very’) and the adjective *όμορφος* ‘beautiful’, with reduction of the sequence *-αο-* to just *-α-*. *Όμορφος* itself is a corruption of earlier *ἔμορφος*, which comes from Classical *εὔμορφος* ‘well-shaped’ or ‘having good shape’, a transparent compound of *εὐ-* ‘good-, well-’ and *μορφή*.

So the modern word that is used in the Greek translation of the title *Beauty and the Beast* doesn’t mean ‘five-shaped’, but literally ‘five-times beautiful’. (That sounds clumsy in English, but think of it like ‘thrice beautiful’, except with five instead of three.)